# How to network a pair of Raspberry Pi's with LDR's so that when one gets activated the other will also activates over network?

Tags: networking, wifi

Basically, I would like to configure setups so that when a LDR is triggered on one RPi with a hand wave, it lights up its own set of lights along with the lights of the second RPi via WiFi. The device is my sister's idea for a long distance relationship gift. We have basic coding practice with switches and **don't even know where to begin** with something networked between two RPi's. We'd like the lights to be rgb so that maybe after successive handwaves it would switch between colors, and having the light time out after a couple hours is necessary. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This a pretty broad question.  It is fairly simple to achieve but is likely to be a steep learning curve.  Have you looked at the resources and help available at https://www.raspberrypi.org/resources/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, each Pi will need to run what is called a "port listener" or "listener service," which is what will receive "light on" commands over a network connection. Each Pi will also need to be sending these "light on" commands over the network.

Your basic requirements are that each Pi has a static IP (so each Pi knows where to send the "light on" command), and (ideally) that they are both on the same network (same router even). You can always do a port-forwarding setup for when the devices are no longer on the same router, but get it working on the same router first.

As for RGB, you can either program each Pi to change colours all by itself, or you can have each Pi tell the other one which colour to turn on. This is simple, just make the colour a variable, and either have each Pi change this (randomly or on a preset pattern), or have the "light on" command include the RGB colour. At it's simplest form, your "light on" command could be just an RGB colour.